# How do you make conversions tables?

Tags: delphi, encoding, delphi-xe2, type-conversion, ebcdic

I need to make some ebcdic_1141/cp1252 convertions.
Here are the tables I found :

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pcomhelp/v5r9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/reference/html/hcp_reference02.htm

How do you make convertions tables from that.
What I specificaly do not understand is what of the hex values before 40? And how do I get the hex values of each characters (which i will put into an array)?

Thanks,
jacob

Comment: In what language? Most languages already include functions for encoding conversions, check whether yours supports the tables you want.

Comment: The language I use is delphi. I did not find any ready to use tables.

Comment: there is no any warranty that ALL the characters would be possible to map, only some subset would be the same. So, "before 40" might be just unconvertible.

Comment: please, specify your delphi version in question TAGs - edit your q and add proper tag

Answer (score 1):

IBM 1141 seems to be already part of Windows NT starting with Windows 2000 at least. Just ask system administrator to install it via Control Panel / Windows Components.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756.aspx

Then, depending on your Delphi version you can

1. use TEncoding class
2. use `AnsiString` wich specified codepage (assign UnicodeString aka `string` from it) and/or use `SetCodePage` procedure
3. use Win32 API `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert `PAnsiChar` to UTF-16, then convert it back to 1252
4. using libraries like `Jedi CodeLib` that have readymade wrapper, doing the #3 flip-flop in one call.

Notice, please, that you should not expect ALL the characters to be mapped between those charsets. Some rare characters like control codes and diacritics may be present only in one of the charsets, and be missed from its counterpart. `WideCharToMultiByte` function mentions this specifically.

---

Alternative approaches (not necessary successful) may include:

1. Aforementioned `JCL.sf.net` has it's own JclUnicode unit, that may have it's own built-in map instead of relying on Windows-provided map. I don't remember if `IBM1141` is included or not though.
2. `IBM Classes for Unicode` may include those codepages as well (or may not, but probably they would). [Has anyone used ICU with Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473127)
3. `iconv` library started on UNIX systems, but with porting of IDEs like `CodeTyphon`/`Lazarus` back to Windows they should have `libiconv` ported to Windows (probably as part of `MSYS` project) and contain Pascal headers for it. Try installing downloading CodeTyphon and see if you can re-use its `libiconv` units in Delphi.